# gcc compile error cv.h not found for Opencv

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, opencv

every time I try to compile a sample program I get cv.h not found, highgui.c not found. I try to go to the includes folder in opencv and did a sudo copy * to usr/includes   and did not help much: i got the following output can someone tell me what i do wrong?

```
stream_server.c:19:25: fatal error: /usr/include/highgui.h: Permission denied
compilation terminated.
uc@uc-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop$ sudo gcc stream_server.c -o streamserver
stream_server.c: In function ‘quit’:
stream_server.c:174:5: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
stream_server.c:177:5: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
/tmp/ccVnjC7y.o: In function `cvDecRefData':
stream_server.c:(.text+0xa9a): undefined reference to `cvFree_'
stream_server.c:(.text+0xb22): undefined reference to `cvFree_'
/tmp/ccVnjC7y.o: In function `cvGetRow':
stream_server.c:(.text+0xc39): undefined reference to `cvGetRows'
/tmp/ccVnjC7y.o: In function `cvGetCol':
```

Comment: What's going on with this file? `/usr/include/highgui.h`

Comment: What does `cat /usr/include/highgui.h` output? Do you really have permissions to read it?

Comment: cat /user/include/highgui.h says permission denied, but this shouldnt be the problem since i did a sudo before gcc on my c program

Comment: and i am not sure whether i copied the right files i only copied from the include folder inside opencv i didnt copy opencv2

Answer (score 2):

The first problem you have is that you apparently installed some file without the correct permissions. Since it seems you can use `sudo`, you might want to fix the permissions on the file:

```
sudo chmod a+r /usr/include/highgui.h
```

(similar to other files you don't have read permissions to).

The other problem indicates that you got your code to compile but not to link. This is most like because you either miss the library name entirely or you have it in the wrong location: make sure you use `-lhighgui -lcvaux -lcxcore`(this is what I gather from the docs; I haven't used this library myself) **after** any translation unit you provide (e.g., after `stream_server.c`; this looks suspiciously like a C file, implying a wrong language tag in action).

Comment: it still give me an error like  warning:deprecated conversion from stream.cpp:36:31:warning: string constant to char* [-Wwrite-strings]  and stream.cpp:79:37:warning: stream.cpp deprecated conversion from string constant to char* [-Wwrite-strings]  and stream.cpp:111:30: warning:invalid conversion from 'const void' to 'const sockaddr*' [-fpermissive]

Comment: These aren't errors but warnings. The first says you are using something like `char* x = "...";` while the type should be `char const*`. The other warning doesn't seem right: You'd need to show the corresponding code to figure this one out.

Comment: stream.cpp: In function ‘void* streamServer(void*)’:
stream.cpp:111:62: error: invalid conversion from ‘const void*’ to ‘const sockaddr*’ [-fpermissive]
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/socket.h:115:12: error:   initializing argument 2 of ‘int bind(int, const sockaddr*, socklen_t)’ [-fpermissive]
stream.cpp:112:28: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
stream.cpp: In function ‘void quit(char*, int)’:
stream.cpp:164:45: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]

Comment: i've also had the same problem exactly what files do we have to copy to user/include.

Comment: This error looks somewhat as if you try to compile C code with a C++ compiler. You'll need to cast the `void const*` you got as second argument to `bind()` to the right type: reinterpret_cast<sockaddr_t const*>(p)` (I don't know how the argument is called in your code, of course).

Comment: Also, you might want to check if the libraary has an `install` target in its make file: Typically, just copying files doesn't quite suffice for installation. The documentation should say what you need to do to install the library and how to use it.